# Text flickers when replacing an image (css and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The transition of the text becoming visible over an image when hovering over the image, was smooth before I put the image and the text into one div. I put the image and text into one div so that I could position the text on top of the image. The transition is now shaky--do you know how I can fix this? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").hover(function() {

      $("img").stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0"
      }, "slow");
      $(".text").css("visibility", "visible");
    },
    function() {
      $("img").stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
      }, "slow");
      $(".text").css("visibility", "hidden");

    });

});
```

```css
#image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 35%;
  width: 35%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#imageblock {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 90%;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageblock">
  <img id="image" src="http://2016.igem.org/wiki/images/8/81/T--Sydney_Australia--Peek_Banner.png">
  <div class="text">
    <h5>NBB4 ethylene</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of the screenshot of the code, can you create an snippet or JSFiddle?

Comment: Or atleast paste the HTML into the question so we can copy.

Comment: Start using CSS transitions.

Comment: On my Firefox it only screws up if you're hovering over the text, which is to be expected. When youre hovering over the text youre not hovering the picture. try to register the event for both text and img. see javascript bubbling

Comment: could you please review my edit suggestion? it's pending for so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the hover event to `#imageblock` instead of the images:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imageblock").hover(function() {
    console.log("enter");
    $("img").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    $(".text").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, function() {
    console.log("leave");
    $("img").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    $(".text").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 35%;
  width: 35%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#imageblock {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 90%;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageblock">
  <img id="image" src="http://2016.igem.org/wiki/images/8/81/T--Sydney_Australia--Peek_Banner.png">
  <div class="text">
    <h5>NBB4 ethylene</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what was going on? You bound the hover event on the image - and - you have an invisible text block covering part of the image. When you hover on the image somewhere in the middle, the hover event is fired making the text visible. Now that text covers the image making the image no longer hovered triggering the second event handler which makes the text invisible. The image is now hovered again and you have a flickers! Notice that there is no flickering if you mouse over around the edges of image i.e. the area not covered by text.